Building component library with nest folder structure using vite
I would like to build a a component library using vite.
But i do not want a single entry point, I want to produce nested folder structure similar to for example MUI. So that components can be imported
import MyComponent form 'library/foo/MyComponent'

as opposed having one massive index file with everytinh or having to do something like
import { foo } form 'library'
const { MyComponent } = foo

as I said, I would like folder structure, not a single compiled file. Similary to what mui does.
I have spend couple hours searching with no success, I only fond 'vite-plugin-static-copy' but that can not be used for source as it does not resolve aliases.

Ok, I found the answer
https://v3.vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app
within rollupOptions there is option to overwrite/add to entry point
export default defineConfig({
  //...
  build: {
    //...
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        nested: resolve(__dirname, 'nested/index.html')
        ...
      }
    }
  }
})

